# Polynomials and complete set of algebraic conjugate numbers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $P,Q$ be two polynomials of $\mathbb Q[X]$, $\alpha,\beta$ be elements of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$. Denote by $\alpha_1=\alpha,\cdots,\alpha_{\mu}$ (resp. $\beta_1=\beta,\cdots,\beta_\nu$) the conjugates of $\alpha$ (resp. of $\beta$). The question:
Is $\prod_{i=1}^\mu\prod_{j=1}^\nu(P(\alpha_i)+Q(\beta_j))$ a rational number?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Let $A$ and $B$ be square matrices over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_\mu$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and such that $\beta_1, \beta_2, \ldots, \beta_\nu$ are the eigenvalues of $B$. (Such matrices exist, since any set of conjugate algebraic numbers is the set of roots of an irreducible polynomial.) Now, the $P\left(\alpha_i\right) + Q\left(\beta_j\right)$ are the eigenvalues of the matrix $P\left(A\right) \otimes I + I \otimes Q\left(B\right)$. Thus, their product is the determinant of this matrix, and therefore rational.

Comment: You can check that this expression is invariant under the action of the absolute Galois group, so is rational. You could also apply the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials.

Comment: Wojowu: thanks. I see what you mean

Comment: danj. Nice proof !!